# How can I use symbolic engine to make harmonic summation in range( j to i-2 ) for ode equation which already need loop with

Tags: python, sympy

```
C = [symbols("N1;%d" % numSpecies, cls=Function, Function=True) for numSpecies in range(40) ]
t = symbols("t")
N = symbols("N1;%d" % numSpecies)
eq=[]
for i in range(1, len(C)):
    eq2 = Eq(diff(C[ i ](t), t),C[ i - 1 ]*(summation((C [j ]*((2 ** (j - 1))/((2 ** (i - 1)(2**(1 - 2)),(j,0,i-2))))
    eq.append(eq1)
```

Comment: I couldn't add all codes I have but my question is mainly about using harmonic summation for a set of equations as part of an ode that already accounts for loop . i can see many examples for harmonic summation but with numbers not symbols indexing to iteration   loop

Comment: Take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are looking for. I am not sure where the time dependence is coming from in the expression for `L`. Does this help at all?

```
>>> x = IndexedBase('x')
>>> s = 0
>>> for j in range(1, 10):
...   s += Sum(w**2*x[m],(m,1,j-2))
... 
>>> s.doit().factor()
-w**2*(x[0] - 7*x[1] - 6*x[2] - 5*x[3] - 4*x[4] - 3*x[5] - 2*x[6] - x[7])
```

And once we see the general form we can write this directly as

```
>>> hsum = lambda j: -w**2*Sum(Piecewise((1,Eq(i,0)),(i-j-1,True))*x[i], (i,0,j+1)).doit()
>>> hsum(5)
-w**2*(x[0] - 5*x[1] - 4*x[2] - 3*x[3] - 2*x[4] - x[5])
```

Just considering the sum of that expression: if the challenge is how to put the coefficients on indexed functions of `t` in that way, you might try this:

```
>>> f = [f(t) for f in symbols('x:6', cls=Function)]
>>> Add(*[(i-len(f) if i else 1)*fi for i,fi in enumerate(f)])
x0(t) - 5*x1(t) - 4*x2(t) - 3*x3(t) - 2*x4(t) - x5(t)
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried your code but still gives me an error: list indices must be integers or slices, not float. the idea is I am representing an ODE with a range(i) from (1 to 40 ) but part of this ODE is harmonic summation with j=1 to j=i-2. I have added the link of equation up

Comment: If you show the code that is generating the error, someone can help. Also, a link to the page with the equation (not the image without context) would be helpful.

Comment: i have added the codes

Comment: What is the purpose of `N`? How many `N` were you expecting? When you use `;` instead of `:` you don't get a range of values.

Comment: Also, is C suppose to be functions named N1 through N40? If so, `C = symbols("N1:41" % numSpecies, cls=Function)`.